# AWS: Failed to connect to port XXXX: Connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, deployment, port

I am connected to an AWS server, where I want to host an Elasticsearch application. For that to work, I need to open a set of ports. In my AWS security group, I have opened the ones, which I consider as necessary. In order to check, whether that worked, I tried the following:

While connected to AWS via ssh, I typed `curl localhost:3002`, which outputs:

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://localhost:3002/login">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

When I try the same over my local machine, i.e. `curl http://ec2-xxxxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3002`, I receive:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to ec2-xxxxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 3002: Connection refused
```

Does that mean, that the port 3002 is not open, or could there be another explanation?

Thank you for your help!

Edit:

The configuration in the security group looks as follows:

**Ingoing:**

```
80      TCP 0.0.0.0/0   launch-wizard-7
80      TCP ::/0        launch-wizard-7
22      TCP 0.0.0.0/0   launch-wizard-7
5000    TCP 0.0.0.0/0   launch-wizard-7
5000    TCP ::/0        launch-wizard-7
3002    TCP 0.0.0.0/0   launch-wizard-7
3002    TCP ::/0        launch-wizard-7
3000    TCP 0.0.0.0/0   launch-wizard-7
3000    TCP ::/0        launch-wizard-7
443     TCP 0.0.0.0/0   launch-wizard-7
443     TCP ::/0        launch-wizard-7
```

**Outgoing:**

```
All     All 0.0.0.0/0   launch-wizard-7
```

Comment: Do you have the port 3002 open on your security group, it will be helpful to share the security group rules you currently have configured for that EC2 instance. You can also run `telnet http://ec2-xxxxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com 3002` from your local machine to confirm if the port is listening publicly on the EC2 instance.

Comment: Thank you, I will share the security group rules tomorrow, as I don't have log in data for the AWS account at the moment. However, `telnet http://ec2-xxxxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com 3002` leads to `http://ec2-xxxxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`. However, I get the some error when I try to connect to port 3000, which is strange, since I can connect to port 3000 via `curl http://ec2-xxxxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000`. Are you sure this is the correct call?

Comment: Ahhh! I tried again without the `http://` and got the following: `Trying 18.159.135.25...
telnet: connect to address 18.159.135.25: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host`. For port 3000 however I can connect. I guess this implies, that the port is not open?

Comment: This implies that either the port is not listening on the instance or inbound traffic to the port is not allowed from the security group or possibly on the OS firewall if any.

Comment: Okay I understand, but since `curl localhost:3002` delivers a reply when I enter it on the server the port should be listening is that correct, so the problem should be one of the latter two?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @WisdomHambolu I added my security group configurations.